# C++ a string which size is 1 but contains nothing

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to read a string and use it to build an `bool` expression.

```
void Parser::parse(){
string temp="";
char c;
for(int i=0;i< _str.length()+1;i++){
    c=_str[i];
    if(c!='~' && c!='=' && c!='|' &&c!='&' && c!=' ' &&c!='>'){
        temp+=c;}
    else if(c==' '){

    }
    else{
        if (temp.substr(0,5)=="false")
            b.add_lit(false);
        else if(temp.substr(0,4)=="true")
            b.add_lit(true);
        else if(temp=="");
        else{
            cout<<"push called"<<endl;
            b.add_var(temp);
        }

        switch (c){
            case '~':{
                string name=get_next_var(_str,i);
                i=get_next_index(_str,i);
                cout<<"i is"<<i<<endl;
                b.add_var(name);
                b.add_op('~');
                b.addparent();
                temp="";
                break;}
            case '|':{
                char lop=b.get_last_op();
                if(lop=='&'||lop=='>'||lop=='='){
                    b.addparent();}
                b.add_op('|');
                temp="";
                break;}
            case '&':{
                char lop=b.get_last_op();
                if(lop=='>'||lop=='=')
                    b.addparent();
                b.add_op('&');
                temp="";
                break;}
            case '>':{
                char lop=b.get_last_op();
                if(lop=='='){
                    b.addparent();}
                b.add_op('>');
                temp="";
                break;}
            case'=':
                b.add_op('=');
                temp="";
        }

    }

        }

if (temp.substr(0,5)=="false")
    b.add_lit(false);
else if(temp.substr(0,4)=="true")
    b.add_lit(true);
else if(temp=="\0" ) return;
else if(temp!="" ) {
    cout<<"tail called, size:"<<temp.size()<<endl;
    b.add_var(temp);
}
}
```

When I try to push the last `temp` after the loop break, I always get a `temp` which is really weird. There is always something I don't know at the end of the temp string.

Assume I get, logically, a `""`, which is `temp=""`, my code will show me that `temp.size()=1`, but when I try to print it, it prints nothing.

This is also why I need to substr my temp to get "true" and "false".

```
string get_next_var(string str,int i){
char c;
string temp="";
i++;
for(i;i< str.length();i++){
    c=str[i];
    if(c!='~' && c!='=' && c!='|' &&c!='&' && c!=' '&&c!='>')
        temp+=c;
    else if(c==' '){

    }
    else
        break;
}
return temp;
}

int get_next_index(string str,int i){
char c;
string temp="";
i++;
for(i;i< str.length();i++){
    c=str[i];
    if(c!='~' && c!='=' && c!='|' &&c!='&' && c!=' '&&c!='>')
        temp+=c;
    else if(c==' '){

    }
    else
        break;
}
return i-1;
}
```

Comment: Have you printed the character number?  Convert the byte at position 0 in the string to an `int` and print the integer.  Not all character codes are printing characters.  For example, blank, tab, newline, carriage return are not visible; other control characters are invisible too.  You can also try using something like `std::cout << "[[" << temp << "]]\n";` to delimit where the character appears.  You could feed the output through a program like `od -c` or similar to see the character code too.

Comment: that is a lot of code.  it would be nice to get a easier indication of the line where you think things are wrong

Answer (score 4):

> There is always something i dont know at the end of the temp string.

I only had a quick look at your code but Im guessing this line is wrong:

```
for(int i=0;i< _str.length()+1;i++) {
    .....
}
```

I suspect this is what you want:

```
for(int i=0;i< _str.length();i++) {
    .....
}
```

And this is why:

```
// Given this
string _str="abc";

// then this is what you will have
_str.length() // 3
_str[0]       // 'a'
_str[1]       // 'b'
_str[2]       // 'c'
```